# If stress is $\frac{F}{A}$, then how can it express the internal forces that neighboring particles of a continuous material exert on each other?

Tags: stress-strain

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_(mechanics)) (among others) defines stress as:

> **stress** is a physical quantity that expresses the internal forces that neighboring particles of a continuous material exert on each other

But if stress is defined as

$$\frac{force}{area}$$

then how can this describe internal forces that neighboring particles of a continuous material exert **on each other**?

Comment: Why *couldn't* it?

Comment: @lemon Well what if the neighboring particles all have different force interactions governing them? Then how does $\frac{F}{A}$ over some area $A$ describe the differing forces of all those individual particles?

Comment: I'm still not clear on your exact source of confusion. But it may help to see the [atomic virial stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_stress) which relates the stress tensor to the individual atomic interactions.

Comment: @lemon Area $A$ contains many particles. How can the stress be for individual particles, if it's for the entire area of particles? Or can you pick $area = particle$ and then you get force per particle?

Comment: It's effectively an average over all of those particles. (Although it should be noted that stress is a concept from continuum mechanics where there are no particles)

Comment: @lemon Okay so the continuum mechanics part I think explains my confusion. But is the Wikipedia article wrong, when it speaks about particles?

Comment: It's not wrong per se. Because, while stress is traditionally a concept from continuum mechanics, it's also applicable to real-world materials. So clearly in the real world there is an atomic basis for stress (and the virial stress above gives the connection).

Comment: @lemon I think the "average stress over the area" also explains my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I have misunderstood what you are asking, but I'll attempt to explain what I think is the issue.

Suppose you consider some cuboid element in your solid and you apply a force to deform it:

[image: Deformation]

The force required is obviously related to the forces between individual molecules in the material (the red lines) in some way that is probably complicated but in principle can be calculated. The next question is what this has to do with the area.

Well if you double the size of the element then the force will be doubled simply because you have twice as much stuff that is resisting being deformed:

[image: Double size]

Since the area $A$ is proportional to the amount of *stuff*, and the force is also proportional to the amount of *stuff*, it's convenient to use the force divided by the area. And this is of course just the stress. That's why we traditionally use stress defined in this way and the strain, because then we get a simple relationship:

$$ E = \frac{\text{stress}}{\text{strain}} $$

where $E$ is approximately constant. $E$ is of course just the Young's modulus.

Comment: If you're going to use shear deformation as an example, then you should give the shear modulus $G$ as the ratio of stress and strain, rather than $E$, which is defined for uniaxial tension.